Do you say a bad footballer is "... a player with wooden legs"?
I watched the football match "Belgium-Slovakia" last night. Belgium lost by nil to one to Slovakia. Lukaku, who plays for Belgium, missed a lot of easy goals due to his poor skills and unsubtle techniques.
Vietnamese football fans often say "a player with wooden legs" to refer to a player who misses a lot of easy goals because his legs are stiff, not skillful or he is not a subtle player.
Do you say "Lukaku is a player with wooden legs" or have similar funny expressions in English?
Urban dictionary has a verb "lukaku"

Lukaku /lu-ka-ku/ verb past tense: Lukaku'd 1. To lose something under
your control; mishandling due to lack of ability and/or concentration.
steve - I really like this girl, everything is going so well!
John - Dont Lukaku it mate.


Mean is not funny. Important to differentiate.

In Italian, we use to have wooden legs, but a friend of mine, born American, was not able to understand what I meant with that.

No such ready-made phrase; you'd have to be creative:  He's not jumping over candlesticks.

@TimR, Urban dictionary has the verb "lukaku"

No, in English, it is not used (wooden legs). That UD thing can be BS. It is used in Spanish. Also, a player can play badly sometimes but that does not make him a bad player.

UD can kiss my grits.

Having stiff legs is a temporary thing and is very different to being a poor player. Which do you want an English equivalent for?

The Urban Dictionary is not a reliable source for English slang, because anybody can just add a made up word.  It's just nonsense mostly, and not meant to be taken seriously.

This seems to be yet another example of the expressions coined by the non-Native English speakers. Sometimes, such expressions are the direct translations commonly spoken expressions in their local language. It is also not uncommon that many languages loan certain expressions from English. Other commonly used expressions are

Long time no see [commonly used by non-native Asians]
Brainwashing [It might be surprising to most of us but it was actually borrowed from Chinese [1]]


There is a similar expression in English, but it usually refers to someone who is a bad dancer: "having two left feet".  I suppose it could be used for a football player who was clumsy/useless.

I have never encountered the phrase player with wooden legs used in this sense.  The only two hits in Google Books have different meanings from the one the OP has described.
Lukaku isn't a bad player.  He just had an off day
Hence I wouldn't recommend the use of that phrase to describe Lukaku, for the reasons mentioned.  We should just say He had an off day.
(Also, it wouldn't be funny to use phrases like that on players or anyone, as commented.)

off day COUNTABLE NOUN
If someone has an off day, they do not perform as well as usual.
[informal]
Whittingham, the League's top scorer, had an off day, missing three good chances.


No, not just an "off day". He has been bad in several important matches, not just yesterday one. Remember how many goals he missed in the 2024 world cup. Your answer is not direct to the question.

The Urban dictionary has the verb "lukaku"
